# Unity Change Ball Direction after hitting paddle in a Pong game (like in dx-ball)

Tags: velocity, quaternions, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling with how to get the ball to change the bounce based on where it hits on the paddle. Normally in a pong game, the angle changes, depending on how far from center the ball bounces, and which direction of the center it bounces.
I managed to do something like that:

```
//rb = rigidbody, velOnPaddleHit = predefined float
float dist = transform.position.x - paddle.position.x;
dist = transform.position.x > paddle.position.x ? dist : -dist;
dist /= paddle.localScale.x/2;
dist *= velOnPaddleHit;
rb.addForce(dist, 0,0);
```

But it's just not working / it's weird.
Can anyone help me?

**Edit**: Here's the video showing this kind of behaviour. When the ball hits the left side of the paddle, it goes left, the velocity doesn't matter

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHX_2DLDp1w**

Comment: AddForce() take a vector as parameter, why is addForce() with a float type parameter?

Comment: oops, sorry, i have a vector3 in the code it should be rb.addForce(dist, 0,0);

Answer (score 0):

You do't change it based on where it hit the paddle. To change the direction of the ball, all you have to do is to flip the numbers in the opposite direction. So multiplying x and y axis rigidBody value by -1 and applying it to the ball should do just that.

if  ball collides with the paddle,multiply the velocity of the ball's rigidBody  in all axis by -1, except for the z axis or the x-axis(Depends on how you setup your scene. It could ether **z** or **x** axis but the **y-axis** **MUST** be multiplied by -1 in other to go in the other direction.

You may have a speedVariable that increases the speed of the ball each time it hits the paddle.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{

    if (collision.gameObject.name == "ball")
    {
        Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(collision.rigidbody.velocity.x * -1, collision.rigidbody.velocity.y * -1, collision.rigidbody.velocity.z);
        collision.rigidbody.velocity = tempVect;
    }
}
```

To detect where the ball hit, the **easiest** way I know about is to use tiny box colliders.

1. **Create** at-least 24 box colliders. Name them from **detector1** to **detector24** 
   (**detector1**, **detector2**,**detector3**,**detector4**,**detector5**.....)

   **Mark** **`isTrigger`** of 24 of the box colliders **true** so that they wont collide with the ball.
2. **Create** a **layer** called "**detectorLayer**" and make sure that those 24 box colliders are in the "detectorLayer" layer.
3. **Create** another **layer** called "**ballLayer**" and make **sure** that the ball's **layer** is **set** to "ballLayer".
4. **Attach** a **collider** to your paddle called. **Change** your paddle's GameObject name to "**Paddle**". **Create** a new **layer** called "**PaddleLayer**" and make sure that "**Paddle**" GameObject is in the **layer** called "**PaddleLayer**".
5. **Position** those 24 colliders from **left** to **right** in **order** close to the paddle but make sure they are **not** **touching** the paddle or the collider of the Paddle. The image below should help you understand what I am taking about.

[image]

**Writing the code should be piece a piece of cake.**

```
bool firstColision = false;
```

1. Check If ball **collides** with **Paddle** with `OnCollisionEnter`.
    firstColision  = true;
2. **Immediately** **check** which of the 24-**colliders** the ball is touching with the `OnTriggerEnter` function.
   Inside the `OnTriggerEnter` function, make sure `firstColision` is **true** before **checking** which of the `24 box colliders` is touching the **ball**.

   The first box collider called "detector1" is positioned on left-most side while the last box collider called "detector24" is positioned to the right-most side of the padder. You can use if if statement or the switch statement todetect which box collider the ball triggered. 24/2 = 12 so **box collider** named "**detector24**" should be positioned in the **middle** and should be considered the **middle** of the paddle.
3. (**ACTION**) After detecting which box number the ball hit from with `OnTriggerEnter`, now you can do whatever you want. For example, make the ball go **left** or **right**. You may have **constant** values that **dictates** how far to **move** the ball for each box **collider** **detected**. That's up to you. You make your own rules from here now.
4. **Set** `firstColision` to `false` to **reset** it.

   NOTE: It doesn't have to be **24 box colliders**. It can be **15** but the more you have have, the better.

If everything works as expected, you can do the final part which is to go to **Edit**->**Project Settings**->**Physics** and make sure that the following is true:

A. **detectorLayer** cannot collide with **detectorLayer**.

B. **PaddleLayer** cannot collide with **detectorLayer**.

This will improve performance on mobile devices.

Comment: No, that's not what i asked. I know how to bounce the ball, but i want to change the direction depending on where the ball hits the paddle. Type dx-ball on Youtube and you will see

Comment: I just watched the video and I understand now. Haven't seen this type of game before.  I will update my answer but that may take long.

Comment: ok, thanks mate. I like that game, because the plain bounce-the-ball game is very boring - you can't actually control the ball, only the paddle.

Comment: Edited that. It is long but report back for any problem.

Comment: I am afraid that it's not what i'm struggling with now. Better way to locate the ball's position is to calculate the distance from the center of the bat to the ball (`float dist = transform.position.x - paddle.position.x;`) just like i did. The hard part is actually in the 3. point of your post (with (**ACTION**)), because it's hard to calculate the velocity change, because i only want to change the direction and not the magnitude of the ball's velocity. So it's a canculation involving Pythagorean theorem... (thats how the magnitude is calculated)

Comment: You said you want to determine where the ball hit on the Paddle, correct?

Comment: "how to get the ball to change the bounce based on where it hits on the paddle. " - how to change the bounce. not how to find where it hit the paddle

Comment: I understand what you are saying and you want to do. You need to find where the ball hit on the paddle then before you make a decision of if the ball should go left, right or just up. You claim to have a better way of detecting the values. The biggest problem is that you have those values in float and I don't know what they are. I don't know which float number is left, middle, right...... Even if I know, it would require you to compare float like if (0.34343f==0.32324f) which is not ok. The method I provided will use colliders/trigger to function and that you can easily do if statements with.

Comment: Also you dont need Pythagorean theorem for this. You dont! There has to be a way of deciding where the ball hit and float dist = transform.position.x - paddle.position.x; is not one of them for this problem AFAIK.

Comment: You seem not to understand my code... And what's about the " I don't know which float number is left, middle, right" ? It's pretty simple. I calculate the distance from the center of the bat to the ball, and then i multiply that by some force. And i've done that, it changes directions, but occasionally it speeds up, and i don't want that, so when i add velocity to the x i have to decrease the y. The magnitude remains the same then

Comment: Yes it is the way.... i calculate how far is the ball then i make a percent from it, so when the ball hits the center of the paddle it's 0, when the paddle hits 1/4 of the paddle it's -0.5, and when the paddle hits left or right edge, it's 1 or -1. And i just multiply the velocity by this, and it works, but also the ball accelerates, and i want the magnitude (calculated using pythagorean theorem) to be the same. (magnitude is kind of a sum of all the forces...). So when i accelerate the ball on the x i need to decrease it one the y, so the speed is the same.......................

Comment: srsly, i know where the ball hits, i just need to calculate how much to increase velocity on x and decrease on y axis

Comment: When I said something about left, right, middle, I needed more info about that. All I was looking for was this statement "enter of the paddle it's 0, when the paddle hits 1/4 of the paddle it's -0.5, and when the paddle hits left or right edge, it's 1 or -1". You finally expanded that.

Comment: Hopefully the value you get does not change each time. Also the value you are getting is more complicated to work with. You will have to write a function that scales the value from 0 to 1 and you can use that multiply and find how far to move your ball left or right

Comment: Hold on I will be back

Comment: When the ball hit the paddle, you get the speed of that paddle. I say speed, I mean velocity from the ball's rigidbody. Store that value in Vector 3, then modify only, the x or the z value depending on how you setup your scene.

Comment: Well increasing the x by 2 and decreasing the y by 2 would be to simple. Wait i think i know how to that. hold on

Comment: Do not change the Y. the Will never change. Assign that new value back to the ball's rigidbody.velocity. Something like my first code answer but not modify the y-axis:

  Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(collision.rigidbody.velocity.x * -1, collision.rigidbody.velocity.y, collision.rigidbody.velocity.z);
 collision.rigidbody.velocity = tempVect;

Comment: So what you are doing is using the old Y and Z values from the ball but only changing the X - value. If this works, then you can scale the value you got by colliding with the paddle and then multiple the x value with it. It can't get harder than that.... Report  back to me....

Comment: Well what i'm trying to tell you, is that changing the x velocity will change the MAGNITUDE of the velocity, so the ball will speed up. And i want it to be at the same speed but with the other direction. Here's my theorem base on pythagorean theorem:

`velocity.x^2 + velocity.y^2 = velocity.magnitude^2`
so,
`velocity.magnitude^2 - velocity.x^2 = velocity.y^2`
So then i just need to get a square root:
`Mathf.Sqrt(velocity.y^2)` and I should have the velocity on Y axis. I'll try that in a second.
The `^2` stand for the power of two

Comment: do You understand what a magnitude is? read that: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html

Comment: Yes. I actually worked on complete ping-pong like game for someone and it worked very much well without problems. I did it like this.  I am required to delete the whole project and cannot go back to it to view the source. What problems are you exactly having when you tried what I said. What happened? Can you explain what happens when you do that?

Comment: My code:
`float dist = transform.position.x - paddle.position.x;
        dist = transform.position.x > paddle.position.x ? dist : -dist;
        dist /= paddle.localScale.x/2;
        dist *= velOnPaddleHit;
        float ySqr = Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.magnitude, 2) - Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.x * dist, 2);
        ySqr = Mathf.Sqrt(ySqr);
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x * dist, rb.velocity.x / ySqr, 0f);`
what's wrong?